# Has the Pascal-like triangle of semiprimes a hidden primality test or there is a counterexample?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, primality-test, semiprimes

This is an observation regarding the semiprimes, also named 2-almost primes, [biprimes](https://oeis.org/A001358), or the product of two primes.

> Basically it seems that if the semiprimes are arranged in a Pascal-like triangle, being the first line indexed as line $1$, next $2$, etc. then, in a similar way as it happens in the classic Pascal Triangle, if the index $n \gt 1$ of the file divides an element $e$ of the file, then $n \in \Bbb P$ is prime and also $\frac{e}{n} \in \Bbb P$.

I was able to verify this [for the first $10000$ elements available](https://oeis.org/A001358/b001358.txt) at the OEIS list.

> E.g. these are the initial lines, and in red color the indexes that divide an element of its line and the elements divided by each index, including in parenthesis the prime obtained when dividing $\frac{e}{n}$ (sometimes an index is able to divide more than an element of their file).
>
> (line $1$) $4$
>
> (line $\color{red}{2}$) $\color{red}{6(3)},9$
>
> (line $\color{red}{3}$) $10,14,\color{red}{15(5)}$
>
> (line $4$) $21,22,25,26$
>
> (line $\color{red}{5}$) $33,34,\color{red}{35(7)},38,39$

For instance applied to the triangle generated with the first $10000$ semiprimes, this is the complete list of prime indexes found (no counterexamples):

> $\{2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,31,37,41,53,59,61,67,71,73,79,89,97,101,107,113,127,137,139\}$

While the classic Pascal's triangle acts like a primality test, because all the line prime indexes are detected, in the case of the semiprimes triangle some primes are jumped (they do not divide any element of their own files), like for instance happens in the case of the line indexes $\{29,43,47,83,103,109\}$

Here is the very basic Python code I used for the test:

```
from gmpy2 import is_prime
import csv

# Read 10000 semiprimes from OEIS into a list
f = open('A001358.txt', 'r')
myline = f.readline()
pos = 1
mylist = []
while pos < 10000:
    myvalue = int(myline[myline.find(" "):])
    myline = f.readline()
    pos = pos + 1
    mylist.append(myvalue)
f.close()

# test the first 141 files of the Pascal-like triangle
# (to arrange the 10000 semiprimes)
for n in range(1,141):
    n_starting_pos = int(((n*(n-1))/2))
    # Verify the elemements of the file of the current index
    for k in range(n_starting_pos,n_starting_pos+n):
        if mylist[k]%n==0:
            # If the current index divides the element, 
            # verify that the index is prime
            print(str(n) + " " + str(is_prime(n)) + " " + str(mylist[k]/n) + " " + str(is_prime(int(mylist[k]/n))))
```

I would like to share the following questions:

> 1. Is there a counterexample? if somebody could kindly confirm if the observation is true or false in some extent that would be great.
> 2. If there are not counterexamples, what would be behind this kind of property? (similar but not identical to Pascal's triangle primality test). Thank you!

Comment: What is "Pascal-like" about this?

Comment: @HenningMakholm separating the numbers in increasing lines with the same quantity of elements as in the Pascal's triangle. And as explained there is a primality property also related to the index of each line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is true but also absolutely obvious, because semiprimes do not have composite prime divisors apart themselves.

If you have a semiprime, say $n=p\cdot q$ where $p$ may be equal to $q$, the only divisors are $1$, $p$, $q$, and $pq$ itself.

So, if something between $1$ and $n$ divides $n$ it is obvious it is $p$ or $q$, so it is prime.

Comment: thanks for the feedback... I think I understood, but then, why it does not work for some indexes like {29,43,47,83,103,109}?

Comment: @iadvd because in the more or less arbitrary division in "rows" that you are generating, no number divisible by that prime $p$ appear in the $p$-th row.  I doubt there is a much more deep reason. The point here is that Pascal triangle has an inner structure. Here there is no inner structure, it is just the sequence of semiprimes divided into chunks of increasing length, but it seems to me that there are no relations between entries (apart the fact they are ordered).